# Adding newly create group to "Site Permissions" section ( XXX/_layouts/15/user.aspx )

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, flow, power-automate

I managed to use Power Automate to create SP groups and add users to them using the HTTP request action.

The problem I have is the newly created groups are created at the "root" (in People and Groups section) level but not in the site in the "Site Permissions" section so user that i add to the group still do not have access to the site.

I created a flow that adds the group(s) to "site Pages" , "Site assets" and to the specific libraries but they don't have access to the site itself since the groups are not in "Site Permissions".

Does anyone know how to add a newly created group to "Site Permissions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a SharePoint group, you need to assign the permissions to it at site (web) level.

Add a new action 'Send HTTP request to SharePoint' and configure the action to use endpoint as below:

```
/_api/web/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=<GROUPID>, roledefid=1073741827)
```

`roledefid` is for Permission Levels which are as follows:

1073741829 - Full Control

073741827 - Contribute

1073741826 - Read

`<GroupID>` is the id of the group.

**Reference**: [SharePoint Group Operations in Microsoft Flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/SharePoint-Group-Operations-in-Microsoft-Flow/ba-p/394446)

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Sanap, thanks a lot for your help !! It works ! I manage to add custom permissions to lists, libraries and items but i didn't figure out simply using "web" would add to the site :-P  thanks a lot !!!